# How to save my data in to next row after clicking a button in excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sheet6.Range("A8:T8").Value = Sheet1.Range("A14:T14").Value
```

The above code copy pastes those values.But When I click the button next time I want to save my data in new row i.e.

```
Sheet6.Range("A9:T9").Value
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to find the next open row:

```
Dim nxtrw as long
nxtrw = Sheet6.Range("A" & Sheet6.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Sheet6.Range("A" & nxtrw & ":T" & nxtrw).Value = Sheet1.Range("A14:T14").Value
```

Comment: @shyamprasadreddy Please mark as correct by clicking on the grey/green check mark by the answer.  It is something only you can do.